# C++11: find a method in a class and Error: incomplete type used in nested name specifier

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, crtp, decltype

With `CRTP` idiom in C++11 I'm trying to check out if a derived class has a method named `size` or not.

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename Derive> struct IsContainer {
    template<typename Der> static constexpr bool has_size( decltype(&Der::size) ) { return true;  }
    template<typename Der> static constexpr bool has_size(...)                    { return false; } 
                           static constexpr bool value = has_size<Derive>(nullptr);
};

struct Container : IsContainer<Container> {
    const unsigned int size();
};

struct NonContainer : IsContainer<NonContainer> {};

int main() {
    Container obj;
    std::cout << obj.value <<std::endl;
}
```

I then tried to get rid  of `template <typename Der>` as following:

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename Derive> struct IsContainer {
    static constexpr bool has_size( decltype(&Derive::size) ) { return true;  }
    static constexpr bool has_size(...)                       { return false; }
    static constexpr bool value = has_size(nullptr);
};

struct Container : IsContainer<Container> {
    const unsigned int size();
};

struct NonContainer : IsContainer<NonContainer> {};

int main() {
    Container obj;
    std::cout << obj.value <<std::endl;
}
```

**Compilation error**:

```
   In instantiation of ‘struct IsContainer<Container>’:
      error: incomplete type ‘Container’ used in nested name specifier
     |         static constexpr bool has_size( decltype(&Derive::size) ) { return true;  }
     |                                                  ^~~~~~~~
```

I encountered such a statement quoted from standard explaining why does compiler gives this error

> 3.3.2p6 Declaration point [basic.scope.pdecl]
>
> > Once a class member has been declared, its name can be searched for within the scope of the class

I still do not get that for which reason the first code snippet does work and the second not. I really would appreciate if someone explains it to me with detail and possibly give me a hint to get around the error of the second code snippet.

Comment: By removing the `template <typename Der>`, you've basically removed the possibility of SFINAE and so
 we get a **hard error**. [Reduced demo](https://godbolt.org/z/b6fWz9zad)

Comment: `Container` isn't complete until the closing brace. So `decltype(&Derive::size)` will give a hard error without the template head as no sfinae can happen unlike the first case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By removing the *template-head* `template <typename Der>`, there can be no SFINAE for those member and so we get a **hard error**. SFINAE happens when during substitution of the template parameter, and without a *template-head* there is no substitution and hence no SFINAE. Note that in the second snippet, `Derive` is a template parameter of the class template and not the member function itself.

`Container` isn't complete until the closing brace. So `decltype(&Derive::size)` in the member function parameter will give a hard error without the template head as no sfinae can happen unlike the first case. See the [*contrived example*](https://godbolt.org/z/jxdch11jq) given at the end of the answer.

---

When you wrote `IsContainer<Container>` then `Derive= Container` and since `Container` isn't complete at this point we can't write `decltype(&Derive::size)` which basically is `decltype(&Container::size)` in the parameter declaration. Note also that *declarations* of member functions are instantiated with the class template. And since in the second snippet, you don't have a *template-head* i.e., `Derive` is a template parameter of the class not the member function, **we don't get SFINAE and instead get a hard error.**

##### Contrived Example

Below is a convtrived example to illustrate the same. In particular, for the following program we will get a hard error as no SFINAE happens for `func`.

```
struct C;

template<typename T> struct D
{
    void func(decltype(sizeof(T::type))); //NO SFINAE here so we will get a hard error
    void func();
};
int main()
{ 
     D<C> d;  
}
```

The error you get for the above program says:

```
<source>: In instantiation of 'struct D<C>':
<source>:11:11:   required from here
   11 |      D<C> d;
      |           ^
<source>:7:34: error: incomplete type 'C' used in nested name specifier
    7 |     void func(decltype(sizeof(T::type))); //NO SFINAE here so we will get a hard error
      |
```

---

Now, let's look at another example where SFINAE happens and we don't get a hard error:

```
struct C;

template<typename T> struct D
{
       template<typename U> void bar(decltype(sizeof(U::type))); //sfinae happens here so no hard error here
       void bar();
};
int main()
{ 
     D<C> d;  
}
```

Comment: As far as I can see, ```only expressions that depends on a template parameter can lead to SFINAE```. I am still confused why ```Derive``` itself, as of the second code snippet, cannot fulfill such a requirement.

Comment: @ImanAbdollahzadeh Because when you wrote `IsContainer<Container>` then `Derive= Container` and since `Container` isn't complete at this point we can't write `decltype(&Derive::size)` which basically is `decltype(&Container::size)`. Note that *declarations* of member functions are instantiated with the class template.

Comment: @ImanAbdollahzadeh Refer to the [contrived example](https://godbolt.org/z/jxdch11jq) given at the end of my answer. It should make everything(the issue) clear.

Comment: I had a glance at ```non-dependent name``` section of [Unqualified name lookup](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/unqualified_lookup#Template_definition). I am now able to distinguish between phase one and postponed phase two for a name. I guess from what you mentioned ```nicely``` and what was written in link, tagging a class member with a *template head*, postpones its substitution later. Right?

Comment: @ImanAbdollahzadeh Yes exactly. Do note however that in any case(whether with template-head or without), the "declaration" of the member function is instantiated with the class template instantiation itself.